# How to define and access array in GNUplot?

Tags: arrays, gnuplot

This is rather easy question or maybe too easy question. But i tried to find the way to done these already and could not find even in GNUplot document. Might be my mistake or misunderstood something about `array` concept in GNUplot. My question is How to define and access array in GNUplot?

Please just provide easy example of array declaration, assign value of array over loop. i think that's enough and i think this will be useful for other people too.

Comment: Actually, the latest cvs of the 5.1 development version now _supports array variables_!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(This answer will be obsolete with the next stable gnuplot release, as the 5.1 development tree now has native support for array variables.)

(The "splot" command in gnuplot uses the keyword "array" to define the size of NxM matrix that contains function values for a 3D plot. Nothing to do with array variables.)

Arrays like what a programmer knows from C, Pascal, Python, etc. do not exist in gnuplot today (gp5.0). They might get implemented one day, because they'd be highly useful to plot a family of curves with arbitrary (e.g. fitted) parameters.

If you are desperate about arrays in gnuplot, you can (ab)use the `word()`  function (and other string functions) to achieve a somewhat limited substitute. It's also a bit cumbersome:

```
array = ""
f(a,x) = a*x
do for [i=1:5] {array = array.sprintf(" %.3f",i+rand(0)) }
print "array = ".array
set xr [0:]; set yr [0:30]
plot for [i=1:5] f(word(array,i),x) title word(array,i)." x"
```

This example writes a set of random numbers to a string variable named "array", and afterwards uses it to plot five linear functions that use the numbers in "array" for their slope. It's handy here that gnuplot autopromotes strings to numerics if used e.g. in an equation.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using Gnuplot 5.1 or superior and need a 1-d array, you simply define the array with size N, remembering that the indices go from 1 to N:

```
gnuplot> array A[3] #Array definition
gnuplot> A[1]=2
gnuplot> A[3]=4
gnuplot> print A[1]
2
gnuplot> print A    #Print the array, with empty A[2]
[2,,4]
```

If you need more than one dimension or are using previous versions of Gnuplot, you can do the following:

Since there are no vector variables in previous versions of Gnuplot, two functions can be defined to get and set values to a behind the scenes variable whose name include the index. The functions are:

```
aGet(name, i) = value(sprintf("_%s_%i", name, i)) 
aSet(name, i, value) = sprintf("_%s_%i = %.16e", name, i, value)
```

To assign and retrieve values on the array A you do

```
eval aSet("A",2,3)
print aGet("A",2)
```

What these functions do is to access a variable called _A_2.

You can build similar function to work with matrices:

```
mGet(name, i, j) = value(sprintf("_%s_%i_%i", name, i, j)) 
mSet(name, i, j, value) = sprintf("_%s_%i_%i = %.16e", name, i, j, value)
```

Comment: Please, someone, correct me if Gnuplot 5.1 implements multidimensional arrays.

Comment: What about array literals? If I want to make an array with 11 elements, do I really have to make A[1]='first value', A[2]='second value' and so on? The words function would not be a good option since each element is a long string (and I don't want to break long strings).

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by @Karl 's answer, it looks even more like an array when putting the `word` function into another function:

```
array(n) = word("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", n)
print array(3)
```

This prints `3`. So the indexing is one-based.

"Multiply" the `array` by 2:

```
print (b="", sum[i=1:9](b=b.(array(i)*2)." ", 0), b)
```

This prints `2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18`. Here the `sum` function is (ab)used to loop over the array and its result is ignored.

And here is shorter, through less generic variant of @bmello's answer:

```
A_1=1.1; A_2=2.2; A_3=3.3
A(i) = value("A_".i)
print A(3)
```

For me it feels more intuitiv. The underscore `_` can be seen simply as the set function. Also it is not limited to integer indices. Strings are also possible which give some dictionary-like behaviour.