# Multiple fit parameters in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have several functions f1(x),f2(x)...fn(x).
Each function is made to fit a data set called v(i)
Each one has this form for example : f1(x)=a1*x
Now i would like to plot all of them by calling a for loop

```
plot for [i=i0:ie:di] v(i) using 1:($3)
```

So far so good.
Now i would like to call a1,a2,a3..etc for each i, for example to rescale the data, and i would write it like this

```
 plot for [i=i0:ie:di] v(i) using 1:($3/a(i))
```

where

```
a(i)=sprintf("a%01.0f",i)
```

The problem is to pass from a string to a float, and to gnuplot to recognize it as a defined parameter. I've tried to add zero to make the implicit cast but it doesn't work. Even if i print

```
print (a(i)+0)
```

Does someone has an idea to achieve getting my a(i) ?

Thanks you very much for any suggestion

Thanks you for the real function suggestion, but i still get the following problem, which can be seen as this minimal example

```
a1=12
a(x)=sprintf("a%01.0f",x)
print real(a(i)) #want to get 12 here
Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
```

Comment: I updated the answer. In your case you need to do `i=1; print real(value(a(i)))`. Hope this fixes the script

Comment: Thanks, the value function was the missing part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **value** function (see `help value`).  The **value** function accepts a string and returns the value of the variable whose name is that string.

For example

```
a1 = 2
a2 = 3
a3 = 1

plot for[i=1:3] x**value(sprintf("a%d",i)) t sprintf("a%d",i)
```

produces

[image]

Here, for each value of i, we built up the name of a variable with `sprintf("a%d",i)` which returns *a1*, *a2*, or *a3* depending on the value of i.  In order to get the value of the variable, we pass that string to the **value** function, which treats the string as the name of a variable and looks up the value.  We see that the curve for *a1* is x^2 (as *a1* is 2), the curve for *a2* is x^3 (as *a2* is 3), and the curve for *a3* is x (as *a3* is 1).

In your case, you can just define your *a(i)* function as

```
a(i)=value(sprintf("a%01.0f",i))
```

and then *a(1)* will be the value of *a1*, *a(2)* will be the value of *a2* and so on.  With this change, your code will work exactly as written.

Answer (score -1):

To convert a string to a float, you have the `real` function:

```
my_val=2.3
my_str=sprintf("%f",my_val)
print my_str # this is a string
print real(my_str) # this is a float
```

from `help real`:

> The `real(x)` function returns the real part of its argument.

if `x` is a string function (i.e. function which returns the name of a variable) you need to use on it the `value` function:

```
a1=12
a(x)=sprintf("a%01.0f",x)
print real(value(a(1)))
```

p.s. you also have the `int` function which does the same with integers

Otherwise, in case you need to store an array (which gnuplot isn't capable of) you might want to look at this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35729052/2743307