# Gnuplot: Switch between plot canvas

Tags: canvas, gnuplot

I have a datafile containing columns with different orders of magnitude. I would like to plot all columns with similar order of magnitude collectively into the same canvas. I do so by testing the maximum of each column using the `stats` command.

I tried so far

```
set key autotitle columnheader
set terminal pdfcairo
set out 'test.pdf'

do for [col=5:125]  {
  stats 'datafile' using col nooutput
  if( STATS_max < 1e-7 ) { 
    #draw to canvas 1
    plot 'datafile' using 1:col with lines
  } else {
    if( STATS_max < 1e-6 ) {
      #draw to canvas 2
      plot 'datafile' using 1:col with lines
    } else {
      #draw to canvas 3
      plot 'datafile' using 1:col with lines
    }
  }
}
```

but couldn't solve yet the problem to switch between the canvas.

The file looks like (1st row are the titles):

```
time   5.000/5.000   5.000/4.000    ...
1e-5   7.6e-23       3.057e-17      ...
0.002  3.4e-17       5.2e-13        ...
.      .             .          .
.      .             .             .
.      .             .                .
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour, and if yes, how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first assemble corresponding column numbers into separate variables and then plot everything at the very end of the script. For example, with `test.dat` as:

```
1   10  11  100 101 1000    1001
2   20  21  200 201 2000    2001
3   30  31  300 301 3000    3001
4   40  41  400 401 4000    4001
5   50  51  500 501 5000    5001
```

the script below plots only the "first group", i.e., columns 2 and 3:

```
fName = 'test.dat'

set terminal pngcairo
set out 'fig.png'

#max. column number in the datafile
N = 5

#inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/35729052/5351549
_group_1 = ""
_group_2 = ""
_group_3 = ""

groupAppend(idx, col) = sprintf("_group_%d = _group_%d . \" %d\";", idx, idx, col)

do for [col=2:N]  {
    stats fName using col nooutput
    if( STATS_max < 1e2 ) { 
        eval groupAppend(1, col)
    } else {
        if( STATS_max < 1e3 ) {
            eval groupAppend(2, col)
        } else {
            eval groupAppend(3, col)
        }
    }
}

plot for [i in _group_1] fName u 1:int(i) w l t sprintf("column %s", i)
```

With newer versions of Gnuplot, one could then use arrays to hold the column indices instead of this indirect approach of storing them in a space-delimited fashion as a string.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!